# Bash grep variable from multiple variables on a single line

Tags: bash, variables, grep

I am using GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). I have a music file list I dumped into a variable: `$pltemp`.

Example:

```
/Music/New/2010s/2011;Ziggy Marley;Reggae In My Head
```

I wish to grep the 3rd field above, in the Master-Music-List.txt, then continue another grep for the 2nd field. If both matched, print else echo "Not Matched".

So the above will search for the Song Title (Reggae In My Head), then will make sure it has the artist "Shaggy" on the same line, for a success.

So far, success for a non-variable grep;

```
$ grep -i -w -E 'shaggy.*angel' Master-Music-MM-Playlist.m3u
$ if ! grep Shaggy Master-Music-MM-Playlist.m3u ; then echo "Not Found"; fi
$ grep -i -w Angel Master-Music-MM-Playlist.m3u | grep -i -w shaggy
```

I'm not sure how to best construct the 'entire' list to process.

- I want to do this on a single line.

I used this to dump the list into the variable `$pltemp`...

Original: `\Music\New\2010s\2011\Ziggy Marley - Reggae In My Head.mp3`

```
$ pltemp="$(cat Reggae.m3u | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\\/\1;/' -e 's/\(.*\)\ -\ /\1;/' -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/.mp3//')"
```

Comment: Arbitrary constraints like "I want to do this on one line" without justification result in hard to understand and harder to maintain code.

Comment: the "one line" comment may have inadvertently limited to answers without pipes, which are arguably still one line.  The simplest answer is just to pipe thru multiple grep's: e.g., assuming  artist="Marley", title="Reggae" (etc), then:  answer=$(egrep "$artist" inputfile.txt | egrep "$title" | egrep "$year" | ..etc...). The grep regexp can be tweaked to match certain fields in the line.

Answer (score 4):

If you realy want to "grep this, then grep that", you need something more complex than grep by itself.  How about `awk`?

```
awk -F';' '$3~/title/ && $2~/artist/ {print;n=1;exit;} END {if(n=0)print "Not matched";}'
```

If you want to make this search accessible as a script, the same thing simply changes form.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F';' -vartist="$1" -vtitle="$2" '$3~title && $2~artist {print;n=1;exit;} END {if(n=0)print "Not matched";}'
```

Write this to a file, make it executable, and pipe stuff to it, with the artist substring/regex you're looking for as the first command line option, and the title substring/regex as the second.

On the other hand, what you're looking for might just be a slightly more complex regular expression.  Let's wrap it in bash for you:

```
if ! echo "$pltemp" | egrep '^[^;]+;[^;]*artist[^;]*;.*title'; then
  echo "Not matched"
fi
```

You can compress this to a single line if you like.  Or make it a stand-along shell script, or make it a function in your .bashrc file.

Comment: Thank you ghoti, however the "Artist" and "Title" are unknown,
how do you work that in... 

for example, Entries are:

/Music/New/2000s/2000;UB40;If It Happens Again.mp3

/Music/New/1990s/1995;Ziggy Marley;Live It Up.mp3

Comment: They're going to have to be known at some point, or you don't know what to search for.  Give more context.  But perhaps you mean that you'll have your search terms in variables?  I'll update my answer with that, but more clarity in your question would bring more clarity in the answers.

Comment: More info? OK. with the following as a line item in "$pltemp"... /Music/;Lady Gaga;Paparazzi... how can I search the Master Music List using field3 and field2 to exist on the same line, otherwise return a "Not Found" ? Also, it's necessary to use a single line of code only.  I'm not sure of the best way to get <field3> and <field2> into the following single line of code... $ echo "$pltemp" | while read z; do grep -i -w <field3> Musiclists.m3u | grep -i -w <field2> || echo "Not Matched" ; done

Comment: This is really really hard to read.  If it's more info that clarifies the question, please click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10942958/edit) link under your question and update your question with the new info.  StackOverflow comments suck for formatting.  A reasonable comment on an answer would be "I've added more clarification to my question; please see above."

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ';' -v title="$title" -v artist="$artist" '$3 ~ title && $2 ~ artist'
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, still trying to grasp this  Is this what you mean?  echo "$pltemp" | awk -F ';' -v title="$title" -v artist="$artist"  '$3 ~ title && $2 ~ artist'  Field 1 is path, Field 2 is Artist, Field 3 is Song name. Sorry about the formatting here, the double space isn't making a break.

Comment: @voiczed: Yes, that should work. You would set the shell variables `artist` and `title` to the values you wish to search for, then the `-v` arguments pass the shell variables into the AWK variables of the same name.

Comment: Excuse me Dennis, the setting of the variable part is what's driving me nuts at the moment, can you please demonstrate if this is feasable on a single line still ?  Thanks much. The line I'm trying to use the fields 3 and 2 is...  $ echo "$pltemp" | while read z; do grep -i -w <field3> Musiclists.m3u | grep -i -w <field2> || echo "Not Matched" ; done ... the entries are in format: /Music/;Lady Gaga;Paparazzi

Comment: `title=Paparazzi; artist='Lady Gaga'; echo "$pltemp" | awk -F ';' -v title="$title" -v artist="$artist" '$3 ~ title && $2 ~ artist'` No need for the `while` loop or the `grep`s.

Answer (score 0):

Well, none of the above worked, so I came up with this...

```
for i in *.m3u; do 
    cat "$i" | sed 's/.*\\//' | while read z; do 
        grep --color=never -i -w -m 1 "$z" Master-Music-Playlist.m3u \
        | echo "#NotFound;"$z" "
        done  > "$i"-MM-Final.txt;
done
```

Each line is read (`\Music\Lady Gaga - Paparazzi.mp3`), the path is stripped, the song is searched in the Master Music List, if not found, it echos `"Not Found"`, saved into a new playlist.

Works {Solved}

Thanks anyway.